# How delete plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to delete a plugin installed within IntelliJ, but within the UI the corresponding `Uninstall` button is disabled, see here:

[image: screenshot]

What can I do now?

Comment: Glad to hear that ... and I think you got a got answer (this is actually what I thought but didnt verify). And hey, welcome to upvote levels. And dont forget to accept/upvote helpful answers. Or other content you find worth upvoting ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is bundled with IDE installation plugin, that can not be un-installed. Just disable it if you do not want it to load.